# How do you mount a VueJS UMD build onto existing HTML?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, umd

I've been attempting to take a couple of small components from our main app to use on a landing page, but haven't had much luck!

I have some existing HTML in the DOM, let's say:

```html
<div id="app">
 <h1>Demo Feature #1</h1>
 <demo-component />
</div>
```

I have the following entry file, `marketing.ts`:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Demo from "Demo.vue";

new Vue({
 el: 'app',
  components: {
    'demo-component': Demo,
  }
});
```

When the output build runs on the site, the DOM ends up looking like this:

```html
<!--function (a, b, c, d) { return createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true); }-->
```

I expected the custom HTML tag to be replaced with my Vue component.

The [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el) state this should be the case:

> If neither render function nor template option is present, the in-DOM HTML of the mounting DOM element will be extracted as the template. In this case, Runtime + Compiler build of Vue should be used.

Furthermore, the docs go on to [state](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only):

> When using vue-loader or vueify, templates inside *.vue files are pre-compiled into JavaScript at build time. You don’t really need the compiler in the final bundle, and can therefore use the runtime-only build.

In this case, I am using the VueCLI (with Vue Loader) to build my output, which from the above I understand to be a runtime-only build.

The component works fine in the full application. The glaring thing I can see is a lack of `render`. When I use that, it replaces the DOM with the whole component supplied and loses what was already inside.

**Is it possible to extract multiple components via a lib build and render them in an existing DOM?**

---

Further details:

- Using the build command `vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue --dest dist/lib/marketing --name marketing src/marketing.ts  --no-clean`
- Using VueCLI 4.2.2
- Using TypeScript and Vue Class components
- This [CodePen](https://codepen.io/getreworked/pen/jprYgW) show's it's possible to do

Answer (score 2):

The way I've done it is by...

1) wrapping my component in a js file

```js
import MyWidgit from './MyWidgit.vue';

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export const mount = (el, props) =>
  new window.Vue({
    el,
    render: h => h(Filter, {props})
  });
```

2) using rollup to generate the code (I think it's a better fit for generating libraries)

```js
{
    input: `./src/${widgetName}/${widgetName}.js`, // Path relative to package.json
    output: {
      format: 'umd',
      name: widgetName,
      file: `./dist/${widgetName}.js`,
      exports: 'named',
      external: ['vue'], // requires vuejs lib to be loaded separately
      globals: {
        vue: 'Vue',
      },
    },
    //... etc
}
```

3) add to html

```html
<script src="/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="/dist/mywidgit.js"></script>

<!-- mywidgit mount target-->
<div id="widget1"></div>

<!-- init and mount -->
<script>
  mywidgit.mount('#widget1', {
    msg: 'all is well',
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This approach won't scale well for our needs unfortunately as we will have multiple components - ID's for each one will become unwieldy.

Comment: This approach was used in a project where there is multiple (10+) widgets that are getting bundled at the same time. The rollup configuration is generated by a function where I pass it the `widgetName`. In my instance, I've passed the names manually (as it allows skipping files easily), bu t you can have a script that iterates through the folder too. I would say it scales very well and I think `rollup` is the preferred way (compared to webpack) for publishing a set of components like this.

Comment: How does that handle:
  `mywidgit.mount('#widget1', {
    msg: 'all is well',
  });`
in your HTML? Are you using Rollup with your HTML? That's what I wasn't sure on, i.e Do you need to write that per ID used on the page?

Sorry, I'm not familiar with the tool, so that could well be the problem.

Comment: Ok, I see. I need to do it individually. The setup is for a "widget" library, where one or two (of many) would be used on a page. But it sounds like that's not how you're looking to use it. I believe I misunderstood your intended use

Comment: Ah yes, sorry that wasn't clear. We're using it more in a traditional sense, where some bits of our app get pulled onto our marketing site via a CMS.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I removed the `--inline-vue` argument from the CLI build and added Vue.JS via the CDN, ie.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
```

I believe this should work from a single lib, so this is potentially an issue with the build tool.

Comment: I'll leave this as an answer to help anyone else, but I don't believe it is the correct approach.